# XSLT : Transform xml file by duplicating tags having attribute value in external file

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have two files ;

**items.xml** : file to transforme

```
<items>
  <item cat="cat_id1">
     <link>link1</link>
     <link>link11</link>
  </item>
  <item cat="cat_id2">
     <link>link2</link>
     <link>link22</link>
  </item>
  <item cat="cat_id3">
     <link>link3</link>
  </item>
</items>
```

**items_to_transforme.xml** : contains identifiant of categories to translate

```
<categories>
<categorie>cat_id1</categorie>
<categorie>cat_id3</categorie>
</categories>
```

I need to transform items.xml by duplicating the tags having the **cat** attribute value in the file items_to_transforme.xml, then change the attribute value

**Wanted result :**

```
<items>
  <item cat="cat_id1">
     <link>link1</link>
     <link>link11</link>
  </item>
  <item cat="cat_id1-FR">
     <link>link1</link>
     <link>link11</link>
  </item>
  <item cat="cat_id2">
     <link>link2</link>
     <link>link22</link>
  </item>
  <item cat="cat_id3">
     <link>link3</link>
  </item>
  <item cat="cat_id3-FR">
     <link>link3</link>
  </item>
</items>
```

how can i do this using **xslt** ? i'm new in xslt thanks for help.

Comment: thanks @michael.hor257k for your quick response. i m using a script shell and i can add a step to transforme items_to_transforme.txt to well-formed XML items_to_transforme.xml. i updated the post

Comment: oke ! I get you, the problem is only in the example file, i fixed it, Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match=
  "item[@cat = document('file:///c:/temp/DeleteMe/items-to-transform.xml')/*/categorie]">
    <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    <item cat="{@cat}-FR">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </item>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the first XML document**:

```
<items>
  <item cat="cat_id1">
     <link>link1</link>
     <link>link11</link>
  </item>
  <item cat="cat_id2">
     <link>link2</link>
     <link>link22</link>
  </item>
  <item cat="cat_id3">
     <link>link3</link>
  </item>
</items>
```

**And the second documentis in a file at `C:\tem[\DeleteMe\items-to-transform.xml`** and the typos are corrected, so that this is a wellformed XML document:

```
<categories>
    <categorie>cat_id1</categorie>
    <categorie>cat_id3</categorie>
</categories>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<items>
   <item cat="cat_id1">
      <link>link1</link>
      <link>link11</link>
   </item>
   <item cat="cat_id1-FR">
      <link>link1</link>
      <link>link11</link>
   </item>
   <item cat="cat_id2">
      <link>link2</link>
      <link>link22</link>
   </item>
   <item cat="cat_id3">
      <link>link3</link>
   </item>
   <item cat="cat_id3-FR">
      <link>link3</link>
   </item>
</items>
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a key for the elements in the second document and use it in a match pattern of a template where you copy the matched element (for instance by delegating processing to the identity transformation set up):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="categories-doc">
<categories>
<categorie>cat_id1</categorie>
<categorie>cat_id3</categorie>
</categories>      
  </xsl:param>

  <xsl:key name="cat-key" match="categorie" use="."/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="item[key('cat-key', @cat, $categories-doc)]">
      <xsl:next-match/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="change-id"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:mode name="change-id" on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template mode="change-id" match="item/@cat">
      <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select=". || '-FR'"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gWEamLh/1 has the second document inlined for completeness of the example but could of course use `<xsl:param name="categories-doc" select="doc('categories.xml')"/>`. Example also uses XSLT 3 with the identity transformation being set up using an `xsl:mode` declaration but of course for XSLT 2 you could spell it out as a template.

Comment: Thx @martin-honnen,  it works fine with saxon that support xslt 3, but i'm using **xsltproc** in a script shell, and i do have probleme with `xsl:mode`.  error : `> xsltproc --output items_output.xml transformer.xslt items.xml
compilation error: file transformer.xslt line 15 element mode
xsltStylePreCompute: unknown xsl:mode `

Comment: Your question is tagged as XSLT 2 so that usually means Saxon 9 but certainly not xsltproc which is an XSLT 1 processor. As I said, `xsl:mode` is XSLT 3, for XSLT 2 you can replace it with `<xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="#all"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="#current"/></xsl:copy></xsl:templates>`.